# SwiftUI: array loses elements in a timer

Tags: swiftui

I have an array of structs:

```
@State var theMoveArray = [moveStruct]()
```

and some other control vars:

```
@State var theArrayCounter = 0
@State var theCounter: Int = 0
```

inside my body, I create a couple of structs, append them to that array, and then I want to print out each element in a timer loop:

```
var body: some View {
    HStack {
        var theMove = moveStruct(moveIndex: 0, moveTitle: "S", movePlayer: "Blue", moveColor: .blue)
        var theMove2 = moveStruct(moveIndex: 1, moveTitle: "O", movePlayer: "Red", moveColor: .red)

    Button {
        theMoveArray.append(theMove)
        theMoveArray.append(theMove2)
        theCounter = 0
        var theArrayBounds = theMoveArray.count - 1
        print("\(theMoveArray.count)") \\print1
            Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0, repeats: true) { timer in
                print("\(theMoveArray.count)")\\print2
                if theCounter <= (theArrayBounds) {
                    print("Timer fired!")
                } else {
                    timer.invalidate()
                }
                theCounter += 1
            }
            theMoveArray.removeAll()
        } label: {
            Text("The Button")
                .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that for print1, theMoveArray.count is 2, as I expect, but for print2, theMoveArray.count is 0, and I have no idea why that is, but is causing array out of bounds errors. That's the thing I'm trying to figure out: why is the array being emptied when it's in the timer?

Comment: Those timers are just floating there you shouldn’t SwiftUI can create and recreate views at will the changes to the State are likely causing the View to be recreated and the Timer is left behind because it is left behind. You have your remember that the value of a State is actually in storage not in the View

Comment: Yeh unfortunately you can't use those async closure based APIs in SwiftUI because View structs have no lifetime. You need to either use `@StateObject` or `.task` (which makes its own object).

Comment: @malhal okay, so I set the Struct to a class now that's an observableobject, but when I try to create a stateobject array, i just get fussed at about Generic struct 'StateObject' requires that '[moveStruct]' conform to 'ObservableObject': 

<@>StateObject var theMoveArray = [moveStruct]()

Comment: The ObservableObject would be a “Store” of some kind. An array can’t be a StateObject. Note that you are also calling “removeAll” before the timer even runs.

Comment: @loremipsum That was it! i wasn't groking that the array was emptied before the timer went off, which was causing all the problems. Or at least all these. Thanks! (insert grumbles about swiftui making no damned sense sometimes)

Answer (score 0):

@loremipsum nailed most of it:

> The ObservableObject would be a “Store” of some kind. An array can’t be a StateObject. Note that you are also calling “removeAll” before the timer even runs.